# Object Null no DOM Manipulation

Tags: typescript

Sou novo no TypeScript e estou com um problema que estou há um tempo tentando resolver.

Estou pegando uma foto aleatória de uma API e tentando inserir ela em um elemento `div`. Porém, recebo o seguinte erro do compilador:

> ```
> (parameter) element: HTMLElement | null
> Object is possibly 'null'. ts(2531)
> ```

Uma das soluções foi desativar a flag `--strictNullChecks`, mas dizem que não é uma boa prática.

Segue o meu código:

```js
const containerImg: 
HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("container-img");

const handleWithImgFromApi: () => Promise<string> 
  = async() => {
      const url = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/338/200/300.jpg"
      const response = await fetch(url);
      return response.url;
};

const showImg: (element: HTMLElement | null) => void 
  = async(element: HTMLElement | null) => {
      const img: string = await handleWithImgFromApi();
      const template: string = `<img src=${img} />`

      element.innerHTML = template; //ERRO ACONTECE AQUI
}

showImg(containerImg);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualquer operação de *query* no DOM, tal como `querySelector` pode, de fato, retornar um `Element` ou `null`, já que não há como garantir que o elemento estará de fato na página.

Há a opção de desativar a opção `--strictNullChecks`, o que, como você mesmo disse, não é uma boa prática, já que poderá silenciar outros possíveis erros.

Uma outra forma é garantir, utilizando um `if`, que o elemento não será `null`:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.foo');

if (element) {
  // Element aqui será não nulo.
  console.log(element.textContent);
}
```

<sup>Link para o [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmWBeGATEwCuq6AdAI75wBOAngMqJzBQiUAUA5MQGYgjsCUAbgBQwgJZcYrBkSj8YAb2EwVMAPRqYAUSSyYAQ3JiYEKgEOYYAMchL%20BCGLLVoSCCTEHAc2m60UYig4AA8oAGFwIPQhYQBfIA).</sup>

Você também pode garantir que o código seguinte não será executado caso o tipo for nulo. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, utilizando `return` dentro de uma função:

```
function getTextContent(selector: string) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);

  if (!element) {
    return null;
  }

  // Element aqui será não nulo.
  return element.textContent;
}
```

<sup>Link para o [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCqoB5QMIJSphQAUAzqgDarRwBOAXIuVPTGMgJSIDeAUIiGIICVomqoAtsSiIAvIgAmcCCBkkAdAEcQqegE8AypLr0KpqAy4BufoOExgiUgEJJGqDwHDfieugg9EhgIFRUdr4Avva%20APRxiACiNJ6IAIa6MCz6AIeIYADHcAVhcJoOQgFQQUgesppEuAQksnZRQA).</sup>

O TypeScript irá inferir o tipo com base no código. Considero esse tipo de construção um tipo de [*type guard*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Uma outra opção é utilizar o [operador de asserção não nula](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`). Cuidado para não o confundir com o [operador lógico](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos) NOT. Utilize-o somente se você tiver certeza que o elemento não será nulo:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.foo');

element.textContent; // Object is possibly 'null'.

element!.textContent; // OK
```

<sup>Link para o [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=28#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmWBeGATEwCuq6AdAI75wBOAngMqJzBQiUAUA5MQGYgjsCUAbgBQwhkSjEocAB5QAwuGnpBMAPRqYAeQBGAK0awAlhBgAHEBAhGdCajHZh8CBJzFIJAQimyFStFCqGtoA0kA).</sup>

Vale notar que esse operador, assim como a desativação da flag `--strictNullChecks`, pode silenciar eventuais erros em tempo de compilação — por isso é necessário utilizá-lo com cuidado e atenção. No entanto, esse operador tem a vantagem de não silenciar erros em toda aplicação, apenas em uma única localidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!